# LaunchUriAsync doesn't work on Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, windows, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to open external link using default app on Windows 8.1/Windows Phone 8.1 universal C++ app, unfortunately it doesnt work. It doesn't crash either, here is code (from Microsoft site):

```
auto uri = ref new Windows::Foundation::Uri("http://www.bing.com");

void MainPage::DefaultLaunch()
{
   // Launch the URI
   concurrency::task<bool> launchUriOperation(Windows::System::Launcher::LaunchUriAsync(uri));
   launchUriOperation.then([](bool success)
   {
      if (success)
      {
         // URI launched
      }
      else
      {
         // URI launch failed
      }
   });
}
```

Any ideas what it can be? I have Internet Client capability on.